# Draw a class diagramm in black and white

Tags: tikz-pgf, color, tikz-uml

I want to draw a class diagramm (and later on other diagramms) in black and white using LaTeX and Tikz-uml as the default color is a kind of yellow.

Is there an easy parameter to attach to the tikzpicture environment or set something up with tikzset?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you can add `\tikzumlset{fill class = white, fill template = white}` to your document to do this. And you can add color to a specific class using a tag like `\uml-class[fill=white]{name}{blah}{blah}`

Per the [documentation](http://perso.ensta-paristech.fr/~kielbasi/tikzuml/doc/tikzuml-v0.9.9.pdf) on page 20.